# Find longest alternating string of 1's and 0's

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am learning bitwise operations in Assembly. In terms of bitwise operations, it is quite forward to find the longest string of 0's or 1's, but how would you find the longest string of alternating 1's and 0's.

I thought it would be something similar to the first two in the sense that you would just need to do a right shift and do the appropriate operation, and then repeat until you had all 0's, but I couldn't figure out the solution. Any ideas on what to do?

Thanks!

EDIT

Some examples:
101101010001 has a string of 6 alternating 1s and 0s. The number 1010 has a string
of 4 consecutive 1s and 0s.
I don't really care for alternating strings of 0's and 1's, so 0101, is only 2 because of the 10 in the middle of it

The architecture I'm using is the ARM A9 processor

Here is what I tried

```
.text
.global _start
_start:

MOV R5, #0//Store final result
MOV R6, #0
MOV R2 , #0
MOV R7, #0
LDR R3 , =TEST_NUM

ONES: LDR R1, [R3]  //Load the data word into R1 
    MOV R0, #0      // R0 will hold the result
LOOP: CMP R1, #0     //loop until data contains no more ones
    BEQ NEXT
    LSR R2, R1, #1  //Perform shift, followed by and
    XOR R1, R1, R2
    ADD R0, #1      // count number of iterations
    B LOOP
NEXT: CMP R5, R0 //
    MOVLE  R5, R0
    B END
END:   B END

TEST_NUM: .word 0x1fffffff, 0x7fffffff
.end
```

Comment: Can we see your attempt Jade ?

Comment: What does it mean to "find" the longest such string? Can you give some example inputs and outputs?

Comment: You say "in assembly" but did not mention which architecture - you can't get a meaningful answer without that information

Comment: I made the edits as was suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the logic that you can use for getting the longest alternating bit pattern:

```
int last_bit = num & 1;
int count = 1;
int bit_at_pos;    //holds LSB
num = num >> 1;
int longest = 1;

while(num > 0){
    bit_at_pos = num & 1;
    if(bit_at_pos == 1 - last_bit){  //Checks if this bit is alternate to last bit or not.
        count++;    
    }else{
        if(longest < count) longest = count;
        count = 1;
    }
    last_bit = bit_at_pos;
    num = num >> 1;
}
// longest is the answer
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an algorithm for counting the number of consecutive 1s, then you can transform the input so that each bit that is part of an alternating pattern is set to 1, and then feed it into to the 1s-counting algorithm.

Assuming that the alternating pattern has to start with a 1, you want to set a bit if it is either a 1 that is followed by a 0, or a 0 that is preceded by a 1, like this:

```
x = (x & ~(x << 1)) | (~x & (x >> 1))
```

then count the number of consecutive 1s in x.